# Visual Studio 2005 not building solutions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a solution with about 20 projects (that use Devexpress controls) in and when I do a normal solution build (ctrl-shift-B) it says everything is completed sucessfully when in actualy fact it has done nothing.  To get it to build i have to right click on the solution and use the batch build option.

I've tried deleting the solution and regetting from TFS and i've even gone as far as reinstalling VS!

Anyone got any clues as to what is going wrong?

Sorry should have added that also tried to build from the main menus aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had similar issues. It's a long shot, but right-click your solution and go to Properties -> Configuration Properties. Check to make sure all of your projects have the "Build" option checked.

Comment: Cheers, that was the problem.  Strange though because I've never edited those settings and it builds fine for /everyone/ else.  But hey at least i know where to look next time :)

Comment: This thing drove me nuts for an entire day. Glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that those settings are user specific and probably stored the Solution.suo

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Ctrl+Shift+B has been assigned to one of the "check-to-see-if-it-is-needed-before-building" type of functions?

Check in the keyboard setting:

- Right-click the toolbar
- Select Customize in the popup menu
- Click the Keyboard button in the lower right corner of the dialog
- In the new dialog, in the "Press shortcut keys", a bit to the right and below the center, hit Ctrl+Shift+B
- Verify that it is bound to *Build.BuildSolution*

at least that is what it is bound to for me. I notice there is an action named Build.RebuildSolution as well, you should experiment.